# How to determine for each point the surrounding area that is closest to that point in a 2d space?

Tags: python, 2d, data-analysis, point, area

I am doing a nature development project now. The area that is going to be nature consists of agricultural land with ditches filled with water between the agricultural parcels. The sludge (mud) thicknes has been determined on varius spots (points) in the different ditches. My job is to calculate the area that belongs to each point. The area that belongs to a point is the area of the ditch that contains the space that is the closest to that particular point.

Just a side node: In some projects we have spot measurments on the land and not in the water. I want to make the code so that it is easy rewrite to code that furfills the same purpuse but then for points on land divided by trenches.

I want to tackle the problem with Python and I will use Dynamo to print the results to Civil 3d. I think I know Python good enough to make the basic functions and stuff to make the code work, although I am still not very good with Python. The main problem for me is to come up with a good strategy to tackle the problem.

I think the main challenge would be to make a spot map so that each area on the map is the area with the space that belong to a particular point. Just for clarity, if you trow a dart on the spot map, you should directly see to which point the dart is the closest.

The strategy that I come up with is the following (see also the corrosponding pictures):

Photo 1 - Determining which points lie nearby a point (p1) with a circel (purple). Then draw line (white) between the point (p1) and a nearby point. Then draw a long line perpidicular (green) on the first line (white) in the middle of the first line (white). (Blue is a example ditch filled with water)
[Photo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HChtV.png)

Photo 2 - Repeat the proces with the next point and join the lines where the first one intersects.
[Photo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb84w.png)

Photo 3 - Expected endresult
[Photo 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vM24M.png)

Photo 4 - Expected result for the next point (p2)
[Photo 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oss6H.png)

Photo 5 - Shrink the area to the bounderies of the ditch that the point is in.
[Photo 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVSc1.png)

I have the following uncertaincies/problems about this problem:

- I dont know how to check if the area is closed
- I dont know how to determine if the circle is big enough, maybe it is good to program the code so that the codes takes a bigger radius if the area isnt gona be closed. I dont wanna make the circle to big because the code has to proces a lot of points.
- Photo 6, I want the area to be ristricted only to the ditch that the point is in. This may be a theoretical problem for this project because the ditches lie fairly far apart. But because I want to rebuild the code so that it works also for points a land where the ditches also form a barrier, I want to tackle this problem right away when possable.
  [Photo 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/842Hn.png)

Comment: While this is probably a nice question. We are met with a long wall of text here and images to click on, no code.
Try to refine your question to necessities and individual sections where you have problems with. People will be me more open minded to help you then :)

Comment: Hi Daraan, thats a bit of the point. I dont know how to approach the problem correctly. So I dont know how I can best start writing the code. I hope I explained that a bit clearly.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.